# getting error after executing the code TypeError: display is nullscript.js:22:22

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

**HTML**
This a HTML page I made to add row in the tables one by one below one another when user clicks on 'add' button and gives me error as below.

```
<div id="adder">
    <table id="adderhd">
        <tr>
            <th>PARTICULARS</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" id="particulars" value=""></th>
            <th><input type="number" id="amount" value=""><button id="add">Add</button></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="tables">
    <div>
        <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    PARTICULARS
                </th>
                <th>
                    AMOUNT
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**
This is a JavaScript code I wrote for it but after executing this I got error on console.

Please help me I am a beginner in JavaScript.

```
function rowAdder() {
    var particulars = document.getElementById("particulars").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    if (!particulars || !amount) {
        alert("Please enter the values inside all the field.");
        return;
    }

    var display = document.getElementById("table-1");    
    var newRow = display.insertRow(row);      //not working (insert(row)); 
    var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

    cel1.innerHTML = particulars;
    cel2.innerHTML = amount;    
    row++;

}
```

Comment: do you need js code?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: When I press the add button, I am getting below error.
TypeError: display is nullscript.js:22:22
    rowAdder http://127.0.0.1:5500/HTML and JS/Web 1/js/script.js:22
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/HTML and JS/Web 1/js/script.js:8
    jQuery 2

Comment: no @sonEtLumiere, I mean 'insertRow(row)' is not working in my code.

Comment: You're looking for an id of "table-1", which doesn't exist, so `display`is null. "table-1" is a class name. Either add an id of "table-1", or search for the element by class.

Comment: Thank you very much @andydavies now it working fine, it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event onclick on the button to call rowAdder function. Variable 'display' is getting element by id, so assign id="table-1" to your html element . Its working fine.

```js
function rowAdder() {
  var particulars = document.getElementById("particulars").value;
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  if (!particulars || !amount) {
    alert("Please enter the values inside all the field.");
    return;
  }

  var display = document.getElementById("table-1");    
  var newRow = display.insertRow();
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  cel1.innerHTML = particulars;
  cel2.innerHTML = amount;    
}
```

```html
  <div id="adder">
    <table id="adderhd">
        <tr>
            <th>PARTICULARS</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" id="particulars" value=""></th>
            <th><input type="number" id="amount" value="">
            <button onclick="rowAdder()"id="add">Add</button></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="tables">
    <div>
        <table id="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    PARTICULARS
                </th>
                <th>
                    AMOUNT
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sonEtLuminere, actually I made use of jQuery click event. But, we can also achieve the task by the answere you have described.